# Why do we not consider infinity in calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

We know that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\log x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ Conversely, $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$ gives $\log x + c$.

However, if we take $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x^{-1}$, from the formula
$$\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ 
We get
$$\int x^{-1} dx = \frac{x^{-1+1}}{-1+1} = \frac{x^0}{0} = \infty$$

But we don't consider this, instead obtain the value as $\log x$. A friend told me that infinity is not considered in calculus. Why is it so?

Comment: If you ever see the formula written down for $ \int x^n \ dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$, you'll always notice somewhere nearby that the formula holds when $n \neq -1$. So you can't just apply this formula to that special case.

Comment: How will you make sense of the derivative of infinity? That's a prerequisite for understanding the antiderivative here.

Comment: @Xoque55 Okay thanks :)

Comment: @T. Bongers Ya right **d(inf)/dx** doesn't make sense.

Comment: Somedays back i had asked same question its just a counterexample to the rule

Comment: I don't think this question deserves any downvotes. All that's happened is that the OP is interested in stuff, and some stuff doesn't make sense given what the OP currently understands, and he wants to know more so that it does make sense. To disapprove of this question is basically to say: "Don't be curious, don't think for yourself, don't ask questions, be deathly afraid of asking things that are silly because omg what if you're wrong?" This is the last thing mathematics education needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is wrong. There is nothing as such like, *infinity is not considered in calculus*. Infinity is not a number, it is *a concept*.

Adding from the comment made by *MathematicsStudent1122*,

> In standard real analysis, the symbol $\infty$ is simply used to
>   denote an unbounded limit. Whenever the symbol is used, in series and
>   integrals, for example, it has a precise definition with
>   epsilon/delta. Similarly, in set theory, it also has a precise
>   definition; we say a set $S$ is infinite if there is no bijection from
>   $S$ to a bounded subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Now for your question, there are two contradictions:

1. Firstly, $\int x^n \, dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ holds true only when $n\not =-1$. If $n=-1$, then the denominator is $0$, and division by $0$ is **undefined**, not infinity.
2. Secondly, the integration formulae are derived on the basis of the differentiation formulae. In differentiation, we have the first principle to calculate the derivatives, i.e. $f'(x)=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

However, there is no such principle in integration. Now, $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1})=x^n, \, n \ne 1$$ So we can say conversely, that $$\int x^n \, dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}, \, n \ne 1$$ since integration and differentiation are inverse processes.

Similarly, we know that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ And hence we have that $$\int \frac{1}{x} dx =\ln x$$
ignoring the constant of integration.

Comment: with the absolute values around the $x$ :)

Comment: @imranfat: That would make it false if you're working in the complex plane!

Comment: I agree with everything except: (1) You omitted the condition "$n \ne -1$ in your first two displayed equations. (2) Anything that cannot be imagined cannot be a concept either. =P

Comment: @user21820 (1) I mentioned that condition $n \ne 1$ in the first point and hence I did not add it in the equations afterwards. (2) I did not say *anything that cannot be imagined*..... I specified that I meant *higher order magnitudes beyond imagination*.

Comment: @user21820 Otherwise you are correct in mentioning that anything that cannot be imagined cannot be a concept.

Comment: (1) I know you mentioned it earlier but it was in a subpoint of a list and so I think it's better to restate it to make it absolutely clear. (2) What exactly do you mean by "beyond imagination" then? If it is something that is beyond imagination, isn't it something that cannot be imagined?

Comment: Your answer is solid but, as noted by user21820, you should steer clear from mathematically vague statements like "higher order", "beyond imagination", etc. Any usage of the symbol $\infty$ in calculus has a _precise_ definition. For example, the notation $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L $ means $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $L$ by making $x$ sufficiently large; this is formalized with epsilons and deltas.

Comment: Well, I think @SchrodingerCat 's explanation helped me. Thanks for that. I've just learned calculus in 11th grade. Maybe when I reach college, I can understand more of what the argument is on. :-)

Comment: @user21820 (1) Okay, I have edited it. (2) Can you think of the largest real or natural number? You can't. So does it mean that it does not exist? No, it surely exists. That is exactly what I meant by "beyond imagination". You simply cannot imagine the largest number that exists, but you also cannot put in an arbitrarily large number if you have to use one, since people might get confused that there is something special about that *arbitrarily large number* . So to generalise, we use the concept of infinity. Have I made my point clear?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 The definition of infinity is not what you have provided. It is the definition of $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} f(x)$. The two are much different. Infinity is *truly a concept*.

Comment: "a concept to describe *higher order magnitudes beyond imagination" that is not true. Cantor did a great job in that area, discovering that there are different kinds of infinity, which has interesting consequences for maths and computer science, and gave means to reason about it.

Comment: @mvw I am aware of the different kinds of infinity. But I am strictly talking of the *infinity of real numbers*, nothing else. If that was where I was going wrong, mention it and I will edit it in.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat That was a mere example. The point I'm trying to make is simply that, in standard real analysis, the symbol $\infty$ is simply used to denote an unbounded limit. Whenever the symbol is used, in series and integrals, for example, it has a precise definition with epsilon/delta. Similarly, in set theory, it also has a precise definition; we say a set $S$ is infinite if there is no bijection from $S$ to a bounded subset of $\mathbb{N}$. There is no need to talk about vague stuff like "beyond imagination".

Comment: (1) Great! (2) No it does not exist. You **cannot say** that there is a largest natural number simply because it is false. $PA \vdash \neg \exists m\ ( \forall n\ ( n \le m ) )$. PS: Since you removed it anyway, have a +1.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I have realised what my mistake was. And I have corrected it. Please check if it is ok now.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Well...I'm quite flattered that you would post my comment in your answer :-). I guess it's better now, in my view.

Comment: @user21820 I am unable to decipher the last part of your comment. Can you restate it? The math part looked a bit clumsy.

Comment: It's standard notation in mathematical logic. $PA$ is the first-order theory of Peano Arithmetic, and "$\vdash$" denotes "(syntactically) proves". My sentence just says that $PA$ proves "There is no $m$ such that every $n$ is less than or equal to $m$.". For more on this, I recommend http://www.mcmp.philosophie.uni-muenchen.de/students/math/math_logic_munich.pdf.

Comment: "Infinity isn't a number, its a concept" is the kind of half-baked nonsense we should be avoiding.

Comment: @goblin: I personally would avoid it, but it does help to prevent students from anyhow using it as if it were a real or complex number.

Comment: @goblin The *half-baked nonsense* was strictly meant for the OP since he says he has just learnt calculus. So that he could get some idea about where his friend was wrong. It wasn't meant for mathematical geniuses.  I agree with what user21820 has said.

Comment: As far as I know, $\infty$ as it is used in real analysis has very little to do with Cantor's ideas. There's really isn't much relating the $\infty$ of real analysis to the cardinal $\aleph_0$ or the ordinal $\omega$.

Comment: @goblin Where have I mentioned that in my answer?

Comment: "The $\infty$ of real analysis" what should that be?

Comment: @user21820 Yes true, but the OP is at the high school level. My assumption is that this is real calculus, not complex

Comment: @mvw: Most often it is the positive infinity of the affinely-extended real line.

Answer (score 2):

To make things come out right,
write
$\int_1^x t^n dt
=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
$.

If $n = -1+c$,
$\int_1^x t^{-1+c} dt
=\frac{x^{-1+c+1}-1}{-1+c+1}
=\frac{x^{c}-1}{c}
$,
and the limit of this
as $c \to 0$
is
$\ln(x)$.

To see this,
we use
$e^x \approx 1+x$
for small $x$ to get
$\frac{x^{c}-1}{c}
=\frac{e^{c\ln x}-1}{c}
\approx\frac{(1+c\ln x)-1}{c}
=\ln x
$.

Answer (score 0):

The [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) and the extended complex numbers are an example where infinity is used.

One of the problems is that one can not extend to a field of numbers, so there are undefined operations to prevent inconsistencies.

Comment: Note that this infinity is simply defined as an object that satisfies certain properties, and is more precisely called the undirected complex infinity. This is of course different from all other kinds of infinities, including the positive and negative infinities of the affinely-extended real line and the unsigned infinity of the projective real line, and the directed complex infinities, and infinite cardinalities in set theory, and so on...